# SQLAlchemy Pandas read_sql from jsonb

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I want to generate a dataframe with pandas [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) from my sqlalchemy query with a PostgreSQL's [jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) attribute to columns.

Actually this will give me my answer:

```
query = session.query(
    cls.id,
    cls._my_jsonb_column
).all()
pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dict(id=id_, **i) for id_,i in query])
```

But I would prefer to unpack the jsonb with PostgreSQL instead of in the application.

My attempt gives

```
query = session.query(
    cls.id,
    func.jsonb_to_record(cls._my_jsonb_column)
)
pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)
```

> (psycopg2.NotSupportedError) function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record

Answer (score 0):

`json_to_record` (and `jsonb_to_recordset`) returns record as if it was the result of a `SELECT` query. In sqlalchemy context, it provides a selectable which can be used like a table.

So you should consider the result of `func.jsonb_to_record(cls._my_jsonb_column)` as a sort of table you can join to you your original table.

That is you query should look like:

```
jsonb_data = func.jsonb_to_record(cls._my_jsonb_column)
query = session.query(
    select(
        [cls.id, <other columns>]
    ).select_from(
        cls.join(jsonb_data, <on_clause>)
    )
)
```

You could even flatten your JSON data using [JSON processing functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) but it is not possible to be more precise without knowing the structure of the JSON data.

Alternatively, I recently released a package to easily flatten JSONB fields from a description of the json data, I would be happy to have some feedbacks: [pg_jsonb_flattener](https://pypi.org/project/pg-jsonb-flattener/)